# Apache Camel with constructor injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, apache-camel

I recently joined a project that makes heavy usage of Apache Camel.  I see a lot of code that looks like this:

```
@Service
public class MyClass 
{
   public MyClass()
   {
      myOtherClass= new MyOtherClass();
   }  


   ...

   private MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

}
```

This pains me, because I hate to `new` an object inside the constructor.  It makes it difficult to test the class in isolation.  I would much prefer to use a form of constructor injection.

In other words, I would like to be able to pass a reference to MyOtherClass into the constructor of MyClass.  Is this possible?

Bear in mind that we're using Camel.  This is a Camel service, and my understanding is that Camel is responsible for giving MyClass "life".

All recommendations welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no @Service annotation in Camel, so its some other framework doing this. Are you using Spring? Then you can use the spring ways of doing this.

Comment: Oh!  Yes, your right.  We're using Spring.  This question is very misleading as it is, since it's conflating Spring and Camel. I'm going to try to get it closed.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)